# Integrating .NET application with Java application - JMS, ESB...?

Tags: java, .net, jms, esb, mule

I have .NET/C# application running behind firewall at customer's site.
This application uses remote component, which is a Java web application deployed into the cloud. These two applications need to communicate two ways. 
What is the best technology to use for integration?
We were looking to implement simple solution - one way communications - from application behind firewall (.NET) to external one (Java) - by doing RESTful style HTTPS requests with data serialized to JSON. Two ways achieved with polling from one side.
But requirements started to grow - now we need retries in case of failures, asynchronous delivery of messages, etc. 
So we started to look on JMS (Apache) and same time many people buzz about ESB (Mule).
Any suggestions and advices would be appreciated from people who did solve similar problem in the past.

Comment: IMO, this question is too broad, it may become fairly complex to find a proper solution. You may want to have a look at AMQP or transport layer solutions like VPNs... Mule is just an integration middleware (or in buzz words - 'ESB'), it does not help you at all making the necessary protocol decisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at webservices and JAX-WS. There are two advantages (over REST and JMS):
1. Transactions (WS-AT) supported both by .Net and Java.
2. Security (WSS) support

JMS interoperability between Java and .Net is not something very solid.

Comment: JMS interoperability between Java and .Net is not something ver solid. That is quite a statement to make. Surely that depends on the JMS provider's support for both languages. I use TIBCO EMS where I work and have never had any problems with interoperability.

Comment: JMS is not supported by .NET core library, only by third-party libraries and products. Four years ago in my previous job we made an analysis of market and choosed Web Services as an intercommunication protocol between Java and .Net because it was the most solid way. Maybe things have been changed for time.

Comment: JMS is an api standard, it is just a collection of interfaces that a JMS compatible broker needs to implement. You can write exactly the same set of interfaces in .net It is up to the broker whether or not they write a client that targets .net and or java. Nothing more.

Comment: Yes, sure. Every protocol is a set of interfaces. But some products and libraries are good for supporting it and its corner cases and some are bad.

Comment: @DarenFox: JMS does not specify the 'internal' messaging format. As you said, it's just an API, middleware and maybe specifix adapters are  required to communicate in heterogenous environments.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at RabbitMQ as a broker. It is an AMQP standard broker that provides both a Java client and a .net client. It is fast, robust and provides security and transactions (if you need them).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Webservices for several reasons.

First:
Webservices are a wide-spread technology which is good supported by many programming languages, vendors and frameworks.
Support in Java and .NET is very good.

Secondly:
Webservices were designed to be protocol, language and framework independent.
Why struggle with some other technologies which might introduce new issues, because they are not designed for this level of interoperability.

Third:
Webservices are flexible, they can grow with your requirements.
Imagen your boss walks in tomorrow, demanding to integrate a C++ or even Fortran application, too.
Webservices can handle this, other solutions might not.

Of cause this is just my personal opinion, but I would go with web-services.
If you want find out more checkout [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/) for Java and the MSDN for .NET support.

Comment: Web services are great in lots of scenarios but let you down in one area Pub/Sub, you have to implement lots of hacks to get it to work and even then its not nice. Igor said that they need support for things like Async delivery of messages which i took to mean pub/sub which is why i recommended a queueing system.

Comment: This is not fully true. Webservices have support for sending requests and receiving responses in async.

Comment: But (HTTP based) Web Services are not in any way as reliable as messaging based protocols (MQ/AMQP,etc). In high-volume environments polling is not an option. Which concrete standard do you mean by 'Webservices have support for sending requests and receiving responses in async'?

Comment: At least SOAP supports one-way calls in both directions. I'm not aware of how smooth this is working over HTTP in a high-demand environment, but if performance and response times are critical a Webservice can bound to a protocol which fits better.

Comment: I agree, but the term 'web service' is just too broad. The transport is the interesting part - we can always encapsulate a SOAP message in an abritary transport protocol.